# my app calls a number that is very different from the number i put when i make phone call from my app

Tags: android

my app calls a number that is very different from the number i put when i make phone call from my app

```
callBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

                    in.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0247873158"));

                    startActivity(in);

                }
```

Comment: what problem you faced?

Comment: your code seems fine. please put a log in your clickListener to verify the number

Comment: I couldn't recreate the problem. your code seems to work... Please check if something wrong with the input you set.